# in R - Omiting some values of the x-axis

Tags: r, graph

I want to plot 180 points on the x-axis with the corrisponding y-values.
But 180 points on the x-axis makes the plot/screen way too crowded.
So i want to tell R only to label every 10th (out of my x-vector) on the x-axis.
Anyone has an idea how to do it?

Code example:

```
y <- c(101:280)
x <- c(1:180)
plot (x, y)
```

Now on the x-axis is every of the 180 points labeled. I want every point in the plot, but only every tenth as written on the x-axis.
Hope you know what i am trying to say ;-)

Comment: that's only true if `x` is a factor, the default is `pretty(x)` which would mark 0, 50, 100, and 150. you can also use `xaxp`, see `?par` `plot(x, y, xaxp = c(range(x), 10))`

Answer (score 0):

[image]After your plot call, you want to use `axis`.

```
plot(x,y)
axis(side = 1, at = x[c(rep(FALSE, 9), rep(TRUE, 1))])
```

Here, I am subsetting each of your x labels via a logical vector by taking 9 FALSE, then 1 TRUE, meaning every tenth.

Answer (score 0):

First plot without an x-axis

```r
plot(x, y, xaxt = "n")
```

then add an axis with a sequence defined from the original data

```r
axis(1, at = seq(min(x), max(x), by = 10))
```

[image]

If the numbers/labels are too compact, then R will reduce some of them (as shown). You can control this many ways, including this (on a fresh plot):

```r
axis(1, at = seq(min(x), max(x), by = 10), las = 2)
```

[image: rotated labels]